# Leoxsys nano wifi adapter installation in backtrack 5r3/kali linux 1.1.0

Tags: networking, wifi, kali-linux

I have leoxsys nano wifi adapter 150mbps using chipset realtek 8188ETV. It works fine in windows but not recognised in backtrack or kali linux via vmware workstation 9/10/11. When i gave the command "iwconfig" it showed "no wireless extension" and in command "airmon-ng" it did not show any dirver or chipset.

Answer (score 1):

All realtek chipsets are not well supported in linux, specially new and rarely used ones. You have to do a little research before buying a Wi-Fi adapter, if possible return it and buy **TP-Link WN722N**, this one has Atheros chipset and well tested with `kali Linux`, `Backtrack` etc. Possibly you are fooled by `flipkart` , be aware of cheap brands like `leoxsys`, `digiflip`, etc.